# Validate IE Specific CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have inherited the following CSS for a site, and I can't tell if it does anything useful. It is included as IE specific if the IE version is less than 8. So my guess is its an attempt to handle PNG for IE's < 8. But whether it really does that I have no idea.

In addition some bots are trying to follow the link `/Content/','').replace('` which I think is how they're reading the line with the `replace` in it. I can't tell if its the bot failing to read this CSS or whether the CSS is rubbish.

If someone could please advise whether this CSS is valid and useful. Thanks.

```
* html #nav li { z-index: expression( runtimeStyle.zIndex = 1, this == parentNode.firstChild ? (className += " first-child") : 0 );}
* html .tabs-container .t{
    background-position:-9999px -9999px;
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.alphaimageloader(src='images/bg-tabs-container-t.png', sizingmethod='crop');
}
* html .tabs-container .c {
    background-position:-9999px -9999px;
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.alphaimageloader(src='images/bg-tabs-container-c.png', sizingmethod='scale');
}
* html .tabs-container .b {
    background-position:-9999px -9999px;
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.alphaimageloader(src='images/bg-tabs-container-b.png', sizingmethod='crop');
}
* html .png{
behavior: expression((this.runtimeStyle.behavior="none")&&(this.pngSet?this.pngSet=true:(this.nodeName == "IMG" && this.src.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png')>-1?(this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none",
this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.src + "', sizingMethod='image')",
this.src = "images/transparent.gif"):(this.origBg = this.origBg? this.origBg :this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.toString().replace('url("','').replace('")',''),
this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.origBg + "', sizingMethod='crop')",
this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none")),this.pngSet=true));}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ ?

Comment: Just updated question, sorry, I wasn't clear that it IE specific CSS so won't validate under proper CSS validation.

Comment: Is it causing problems? If it only gets included by IE with versions < 8, can't you just leave it in. It will get less and less use as time progresses and IE7 becomes less prevalent. And are you sure about the bots? Do bots interpret conditional comments?

Comment: That is the problem its causing, I get 404 errors on the site from time to time as bots (yes I'm sure) attempt to access the URL I gave in the second para. If I knew it was an issue with the bot I'd just leave it, but on the other hand if I knew the code was accomplishing nothing I'd remove it - hence this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not valid, but it could be useful. Some CSS hacks require invalid CSS to enforce a specific behaviour on a specific browser while leaving the others untouched.

Does anything change if you remove it? If not, it's not useful. :)

It seems to me that this CSS is to allow transparent PNG images. I think those were not supported in IE6. So if you still need to support IE6, you might still need this, but I wouldn't.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about the site to know if its useful. Hence why I would like some expert option as to whether its valid for what its trying to do. I did guess it might be something to do with png, but I don't know the IE conditional CSS well enough to judge. So I'm looking for someone who can actually tell whether that could be valid in an IE only context or whether it wouldn't even work there.

Comment: BoltClock - can you say more please.

Comment: Well, I am quite sure this code is about displaying transparent png images. My memory failed in the browser version: it is needed in IE7 as well. That also means that you should be able to see the effect of any changes when you look for the element matched by `.tabs-container .c` in IE7. But I agree with MrLister's comment: If you use a conditional comment to make sure this CSS is only loaded in IE7 and before, it shouldn't interfere with any other browser, nor bot (unless someone wrote a bot using the IE7 type library, but that's not so likely).